# When do use where to?

Tags: questions

When someone is asking where are they heading, they ask you '**where to**'? Why is that they say this instead of just '**where**'?

Comment: Because we don't say *I'm heading London.* It's *I'm heading **to** London.* The figurative use of the verb ***to head*** in the sense of ***travel*** (towards somewhere / in a specific direction) always requires the preposition ***to*** before a location. But not before a *direction*, as in ***We're heading north tomorrow***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Where to?" would be used only in a situation when there is no context that would make it clear.

E. g., when we are dealing with full questions "Where are we?" vs. "Where are we going?", it is clear which meaning "where" has here—whether of location or of direction of movement. Other languages have different words for this; e. g. in German it's the difference between "wo" and "wohin" (the latter being "where to").

Really, the only situation where I'd envision "Where to?" to be useful is when you and another person get into a car (you are driving), and you are asking "Where to?"

This is a replacement for a longer phrase "Where should we be going now?", and the short version needs to make it clear that we are talking about the meaning of *direction of movement*. So that is why asking just "Where?", in the absence of context, would not be enough.

Comment: I get the context, but there's something wrong about the grammar... makes me 'just a bit' confused. In a nutshell, its good.

Comment: @JohnArvin "Where to" is very much colloquial, and really limited to this situation of an "incomplete" sentence which I've described. If a sentence is more complete, it will be only "where".